# Prove or disprove that H is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $H= \{a+bi:a,b \in \mathbb{R}, ab \geq 0\}.$ Prove or disprove that $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$ under addition.

I know to show that $H$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{C}$ it has to show that:

1. $H \neq \emptyset$.
2. $H$ is closed.
3. $H$ has an inverse.

   1. Since $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$, then we can clearly see that 
      $H \neq \emptyset$.
   2. Suppose $x$, $y \in H$ then $x= a_1+b_1i$ and $y=a_2+b_2i$ then $x+y \rightarrow a_1+b_1i+a_2+b_2i$ am I taking this on the right direction?
   3. To find the inverse then $x^-1=(a+bi)^{-1} = (bi)^-1+(a)^{-1}=  (a)^{-1}+(bi)^{-1} $since $\mathbb{C}$ is abelian.

This is the approach I took.

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
3+4i &\in& H \\
-4-3i &\in& H \\
(3+4i)+(-4-3i)=-1+i &\notin& H \\
\end{array}$$

---

There are three fatal flaws in your attempt:

1. You didn't actually prove that $x+y \in H$. You just computed $x+y$ which is a complex number, but this doesn't mean it is in $H$.
2. This is a group under addition. Your choice of $\cdot^{-1}$ makes it look like you are considering the multiplicative inverse, when actually the inverse of $a+bi$ is $-a-bi$. I'm not sure if you actually know this.
3. Again, you haven't proved that the inverse is again in $H$.

Comment: can you explain how you got the $-4-3i \in H$?

Comment: @Killercamin $(-4)(-3) = 12 \ge 0$

Comment: Oh i see, so i was going on the right direction but forgot to add values?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: isn't your example that h is not closed, so my "proof" to show that is closed is wrong. right?

Comment: @Killercamin I've edited my answer to argue why your proof is wrong.